# How do I add wireless-router to existing VPN-router>DHCP-server network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

Our office just acquired a Cisco/Linksys RVL200 VPN Router for use as our primary router. We handle DHCP serving via dhcpd on a Debian server. I want to enable wireless access to our network. We have a Linksys WRT54G v5- and I'm having some difficulty setting it up to work correctly, please help!

Comment: I would suggest posting further details regarding the current shape of your network. (Hint: Diagrams are easier to understand than text!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is strange (to me) - but seems to be what fixed my issue: "Connect from the primary router's LAN port to one of the LAN ports on the secondary router", via [link text](http://forums.techguy.org/networking/557009-cascading-2-wireless-routers.html). I was plugged into the Internet (incoming) port. Besides this detail, all routing functions of the wireless router were disabled and it fit right in to the network.

Modem
|
VPN Router
|
switch, wireless router (gateway)
|
dhcpd server

I wonder if we should have our dhcpd server above/before our switch...but if it ain't broke, don't fix it + that's another topic.